# Magento how i inistall oAuth on lamp server? (Ubuntu Os)

Tags: php, magento, oauth, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4 and local lamp server on ubuntu.İ want to Create a simple product as an Admin user with OAuth authentication. i also generated consumer key and consumer secret key but i cant install oauth on lamp server.

My Codes are in this link->

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html
But i'm taking error because i haven't got api folder in magento file. i dont have also auth/token file.

My Error occurs like this->

> "Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Example1/index.php on line 36"

Error code is here ->

```
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
```

Do I need library of auth.php for Oauth class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `http://localhost/`, go to php info() and search for oauth. If it is not there, try the below things,

install oauth for specifiv php version

`sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev` for php 5.* versions or

```
apt-get install php5-dev libpcre-dev

sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install oauth-1.2.3
```

in php.ini file add the line

> extension=oauth.so

then restart the server and search again for oauth.

Comment: Ty for answer it works for me class defined. When authantication i want to retrieve order list from magento but i dont have localhost/oauth/token'; oauth file is not exist in magento directory so error occurs. How i assing this parameter to $accessTokenRequestUrl variable?